# How do I add a folder to run PHP scripts in Nuxt Project folder?

Tags: vue.js, nginx, nuxt.js

I have a working Nuxt website configured using Nginx web server.

What I want to do is that I want to run some demo PHP script from a folder called **demo** which is placed inside root folder of the project.

Now if I access it like this: http://mywebsite.com/demo/test.php 
It works fine but If I add a folder with more scripts and css files like this
http://mywebsite.com/demo/todo_list/index.php
Here the index.php is loaded with some images, css and js files. But the page on browser only executes the php code. It can't load any resources like js, css and image files.
Basically I want this folder to be independent so I can do my research work from this folder making it completely independent from Nuxt.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured out.
Just had to add one more rule inside nginx config file as below

```
# Demo Folder
location /demo/ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```